# Will Microsoft support WAP3-Open and WPA3-Enterprise in upcoming releases?

Tags: windows-10, device-driver, wpa

From MSDN documentation([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/wpa3-sae-authentication)), I found that currently, Windows 10 is supporting only WPA3-SAE authentication. Can we expect support for WAP3-Open and WPA3-Enterprise in future Windows 10 releases?

Thanks
Sathish

Comment: from what I see 1903 supports WPA3 which is enterprise while SAE is for consumers.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find any comment from Microsoft regarding support for WPA3-Open or WPA3-Enterprise in future versions.

I assume eventually, but until they release something it is just guessing.

#### Update

Support for WPA3 Enterprise and Opportunistic Wireless Encryption (OWE)  aka Enhanced Open was added in the Windows 10 May 2020 Update (version 2004/20H1)